# How to refresh graduated symbology legend in layers panel using python in QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

In QGIS 2.x, I used the following code to refresh a graduated symbology legend in the layers panel:

```
self.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(self.myLayer)
```

The new QGIS 3 API advises to use QgsLayerTreeNode instead, but the only way I found to get it working is the following code :

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
model = self.iface.layerTreeView().model()
model.refreshLayerLegend(root.findLayer(self.myLayer.id()))
```

... which looks rather cumbersome. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use this:

```
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Gary, I am very proud to get an answer from QGIS project founder himself !

Answer (score 2):

your code is correct,maybe you can use two lines only,for example.

```
node = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(self.myLayer.id())
self.iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel().refreshLayerLegend(node)
```

it's a proposal

Comment: In QGIS 3.2.2 this worked for me.